# Participles with conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, participles

I wonder which of the following sentences are grammatically correct? Is there is a technical term for this kind of structure.

> **On** watching the news, I immediately called him.
>
> **As soon as** watching the news, I immediately called him.
>
> **The moment** watching the news, I immediately called him.

---

This question is from a test. For me the first two sound okay but I cannot explain if one them is wrong.

Comment: Is this from a test? What is your own guess regarding this?

Comment: @CowperKettle Yes .This question is from a test. For me the first two sound okay but I cannot explain if one them is wrong.

Comment: I can't really explain what a non-finite clause is, but I can say that **as soon as** or **the moment (that)** require a complete clause after them, and that means a subject and a verb.  "watching the news" doesn't have a subject doing a verb, so it doesn't work with those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As soon as watching the news, I immediately called him.

This sentence is incorrect grammatically. Why? Because the expression **as soon as** cannot take a [non-finite clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause) ("watching the news").

It can take a finite clause:

> As soon as **I watched the news**, I immediately called him.

Furthermore, "as soon as" is synonymous with "immediately after" so you might have felt some oddnes of the whole sentence.

> Immediately after watching the news I immediately called him.

Comment: Thank you. I know what non-finite clause means but do you have a link for a resource that explains " as soon as cannot take a non-finite clause"